# How to correctly map through an array of objects

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array of objects (`$grow`):

```
class ArrayObject#48 (1) {
  private $storage =>
  array(4) {
    [0] =>
    class stdClass#84 (3) {
      public $id =>
      string(5) "1"
      public $name =>
      string(5) "dasdasd"
      public $pimba =>
      string(2) "kl"
    }
    [1] =>
    class stdClass#46 (3) {
      public $id =>
      string(5) "2"
      public $name =>
      string(5) "sadwqq"
      public $pimba =>
      string(2) "kl"
    }
    [2] =>
    class stdClass#83 (3) {
      public $id =>
      string(5) "3"
      public $name =>
      string(5) "bbbbbb"
      public $pimba =>
      string(2) "kl"
    }
    [3] =>
    class stdClass#43 (3) {
      public $id =>
      string(5) "3"
      public $name =>
      string(5) "aaaaaa"
      public $pimba =>
      string(2) "kl"
  }
}
```

I'm unable to use `array_map`, it's always returning **null**. I think it's because the `private $storage` but I don't know how to fix it.

```
array_push($arr, array_map(function($c) {
    return $c;
},$grow));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`array_map`](https://www.php.net/array_map) expects an array as its second parameter. You're passing an [`ArrayObject`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) to it.

You'll want to use [`iterator_to_array`](https://www.php.net/iterator_to_array) to convert that object (which is an iterator, as it implements `Traversable`) into an array:

```
array_map(function ($c) {
  // ... do stuff with $c
  return $c;
}, iterator_to_array($grow))
```

Side note: you should use `$array[] = $value;` instead of `array_push($array, $value);` as it's both handier and quicker.

By the way, I'm not sure you want to push into your array in this case. This will add a sub-array to your existing `$arr` array. Depending on what you're attempting to do, `array_merge` may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you. My final variable should be just an array of objects so at the end i'll iterate with it by doing `foreach(item in itens)`. I tried with `$array[]=$val`, but this way I had a bunch of "arrays of object arrays". I need a single array of objects. I'll check `array_merge`. Thanks for this complete superB answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way:

```
array_push($arr, array_map(function($c) {
    return $c;
},$grow->getArrayCopy()));
```

You can check this [Doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/arrayobject.getarraycopy.php). Hope help you.